# Spring Oauth2 Couldn't Obtain Access Token Issue

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I'm having trouble setting up a Spring Oauth2 server. When I point the client to FB, it logs in fine, when I direct it to my Oauth2 server, it is not working. The user can log in successfully and can get bearer tokens.  I'm getting back **"BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token"** from the client.

Server logs:

```
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@4f2698f7. A new one will be created.
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
 o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher o.s.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5b5aeff5
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
 w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Request is to process authentication
 o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using o.s.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
 s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to o.s.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@1b8f3b15
 w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: o.s.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4bc9b896: Principal: o.s.security.core.userdetails.User@f02988d6: Username: username; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: A5769D3F7BE48CDCE28246573B9CF1D9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
 RequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler : Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa
 o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa'
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext 'o.s.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@4bc9b896: Authentication: o.s.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4bc9b896: Principal: o.s.security.core.userdetails.User@f02988d6: Username: username; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: A5769D3F7BE48CDCE28246573B9CF1D9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@4f2698f7
 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'o.s.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@4bc9b896: Authentication: o.s.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4bc9b896: Principal: o.s.security.core.userdetails.User@f02988d6: Username: username; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: A5769D3F7BE48CDCE28246573B9CF1D9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
 o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher o.s.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5b5aeff5
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/logout'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /oauth/authorize' doesn't match 'POST /login
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
 o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
 o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: arg1=client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa; arg2=client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa (property equals)
 o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURI: arg1=/oauth/authorize; arg2=/oauth/authorize (property equals)
 o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : serverPort: arg1=8081; arg2=8081 (property equals)
 o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURL: arg1=http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize; arg2=http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize (property equals)
 o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : scheme: arg1=http; arg2=http (property equals)
 o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : serverName: arg1=localhost; arg2=localhost (property equals)
 o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : contextPath: arg1=; arg2= (property equals)
 o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : servletPath: arg1=/oauth/authorize; arg2=/oauth/authorize (property equals)
 o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Removing DefaultSavedRequest from session if present
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'o.s.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4bc9b896: Principal: o.s.security.core.userdetails.User@f02988d6: Username: username; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: A5769D3F7BE48CDCE28246573B9CF1D9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
 o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa; Attributes: [permitAll]
 o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: o.s.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4bc9b896: Principal: o.s.security.core.userdetails.User@f02988d6: Username: username; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: A5769D3F7BE48CDCE28246573B9CF1D9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
 o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: o.s.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@38a2b5af, returned: 1
 o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
 o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login&response_type=code&state=CIjAxa reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
 .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/authorize
 .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public o.s.web.servlet.ModelAndView o.s.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,o.s.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)]
 o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/css/**'
 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/js/**'
 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/images/**'
 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/error'
 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
 o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher o.s.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@460f0137
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'o.s.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
 o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
 o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
 o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: o.s.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
 o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: o.s.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@30d9792, returned: -1
 o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

o.s.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at o.s.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at o.s.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at o.s.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at o.s.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
...
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]

o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /**
o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=o.s.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@244013bc, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/json
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/atom+xml .isCompatibleWith application/json = false
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/x-www-form-urlencoded .isCompatibleWith application/json = false
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/json = true
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing o.s.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint@33884c2a
s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer : Written [error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"] as "application/json" using [o.s.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@71d92e6a]
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Related files:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth-server-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>oauth-server-test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>o.s.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>o.s.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>o.s.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>o.s.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>o.s.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>o.s.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>o.s.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>o.s.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: oauth-server-test
  resources:
    chain:
      enabled: true
management:
  context_path: /admin
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
server:
  port: 8081
```

WebSecurityConfiguration.java:

```
package com.example;

import ...

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).withUser("username")
                .password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

OAuth2AuthorizationConfig.java:

```
package com.example;

import ...

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
            throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .approvalStoreDisabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource)
                .withClient("clientId")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "password")//, "authorization_code")
                .scopes("read")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .and()
                .withClient("clientIdPassword")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read");
    }
}
```

OauthServerTestApplication.java:

```
package com.example;

import ...

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class OauthServerTestApplication {

    @Autowired private DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OauthServerTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping({ "/user", "/me" })
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("name", principal.getName());
        return map;
    }
}
```

The client logs:

```
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/login' matched by universal pattern '/**'
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login?code=N2L54X&state=7hQn1L at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login?code=N2L54X&state=7hQn1L at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1e0a5c49. A new one will be created.
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login?code=N2L54X&state=7hQn1L at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher o.s.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@463f1d5c
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login?code=N2L54X&state=7hQn1L at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login?code=N2L54X&state=7hQn1L at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy        : /login?code=N2L54X&state=7hQn1L at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Retrieving token from http://localhost:8081/oauth/token
g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[N2L54X], redirect_uri=[http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/login], client_id=[clientId], client_secret=[secret]}
uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: o.s.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Delegating to authentication failure handler o.s.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@55e17d56
.a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

application.yml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: clientId
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8081/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8081/user
spring:
  resources:
    chain:
      enabled: true
server:
  port: 8080
  context_path: /client
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to change the clientId and secret, it is not the same with facebook and with your oauth2 server.

Comment: That client ID and secret is correct to what I have set in my server.  If I change the config no the client app and point it to FB, I would update it along with the URL's and it works.  I can get the client to work with FB, just not my server.  You can see it matches up with OAuth2AuthorizationConfig.java

Comment: The goal is not to use FB credentials, but one in a local store.

Comment: @FiguringThisOut have resolved it ? I met the same err